# Undefined method for a type

Tags: java, recursion

I'm trying to implement a program which counts the number of possibilities to get a specific amount out of a list of coins, but I get the error

> the method coins(int) is undefined for the type Money" in this row at coins(s-1):
>   return comb(s-1, amount, coins) + comb(s, amount-coins(s-1), coins);

Here is my code

```
class List<T> {
T head;
List<T> tail;

List(T head, List<T> tail) {
    this.head = head;
    this.tail = tail;
}
static <U> List<U> node(U head, List<U> tail) {
    return new List<U>(head, tail);
}
}

public class Money{

//should count number of combinations to get change amount amount

static int comb(int s, int amount, List<Integer> coins) { 
         if (amount == 0 ) 
                return 1;

     else if (amount < 0) 
            return 0;

     return comb(s-1, amount, coins) + comb(s, amount-coins(s-1), coins);
```

What is the problem?

Comment: Why are you using your own `List` class? It's confusing to name it *exactly* like [Java's `List` interface](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html), and it doesn't seem to have any advantage over a regular `ArrayList` or `LinkedList`.

Answer (score 1):

I think your problem is how you are trying to access elements of a list.

```
return comb(s-1, amount, coins) + comb(s, amount-coins(s-1), coins);
```

should be:

```
return comb(s-1, amount, coins) + comb(s, amount-coins.get(s-1), coins);
```

Coins is a list, so you should use coins.get(index) to access a single element. [Here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/interfaces/list.html) is some more information on Lists in Java.

Comment: thanks, i already tried that one. it doesnt work though and gives me the error " the method get(int) is undefined for the type List<Integer>"... any other ideas? :)

Comment: @user3157144 Because **your** `List` implementation doesn't have a `get(int)` method. connor probably assumed that you were using the standard Java `List` interface, which *does* have a `get(int)` method.

Comment: ok thanks! is there an easy way to implement my own get(int) method?

Comment: That's correct. I didn't pay attention to the first part when I thought I'd found the error. You can use the standard list or add get() functionality to your custom one

Comment: Why do you need to implement your own list?

Comment: @user3157144 I don't see why you'd want to bother with implementing it yourself, unless you have some very special needs. Don't reinvent the wheel, just throw away your own implementation and use `java.util.List` instead.

Comment: i am not allowed to use the standard list.. do you know how to quickly implement my own get(index) method?

Comment: or maybe any other ideas how I can do this without the get method?

Comment: It looks to me like you have some work to do on your list. I'd take a look at this page: http://www.danielacton.com/Data-Structures/Linked-List/Java/

Comment: Also, I'd recommend naming your class something other than "List"

Comment: ok, maybe i am on the wrong way :( do you have a hint how I can count the number of possibilities without working on my list implementation?